How to understand the <- in Haskell's do notation with an uncommon ">>=" implementation in a Monad?
I am a C++/Rust programmer, and out of curiosity, I am currently learning Haskell. As expected, I encountered some obstacles while trying to understand Monads:
I have already read about the definition of Monads on Wikibook, including their relationship to the mathematical definition in category theory and the three Monad laws. I also understand that the do notation is syntactic sugar for Monads, but certain behaviors in do blocks continue to puzzle me.
In some tutorials, I've noticed that bind (>>=) is often explained as applying the second argument (a function) to the value contained within the first argument and return the result of applying the function. However, from the perspective of Monad laws, this doesn't seem to be the only possible implementation. I'm not sure if bind must always follow this pattern or if it's just a common implementation.
If this pattern is indeed common, then I have to consider other implementations. What confuses me the most is that we know:
do { v <- y; ... } = y >>= (\v -> ...)

So the meaning of <- here should be directly related to the implementation of >>=. But if it’s not the common implementation mentioned above, then <- might no longer carry the semantics of declaration or binding. How should we understand it in such cases?
Unfortunately, as a beginner, I haven't yet thought of an example of an uncommon but law-abiding implementation of bind, despite my efforts.

Here's the summary of my questions:

Does there exist an uncommon implementation of bind (>>=) that still satisfies the Monad laws?
Under what I believe to be an uncommon implementation of bind, How to understand the meaning of <- in a do notation?


No indeed, it has not per se the same semantics as a C-style assignment, in fact in Haskell there is no assignment, only declarations.

That's right. I'll change the 'C-style assignment' into 'declarations' in question

Your definition of "common" doesn't make sense: there's no "value" "contained" in an element of the type IO a. The only way to make sense of this is via the type of (>>=), m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b, and of course every implementation has to match this type.

It is purely syntactic sugar. x <- y; z is the same as y >>= (\x -> z), nothing more, nothing less. It is a text level transformation. What the symbols actually mean is irrelevant.

@n.m.couldbeanAI I think the reason why do notation exists is to use monad to split it into something like procedural programming, and to say that I can't understand <- to desugered it is seem to give up its original purpose.

I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean by "give up its original purpose." Maybe you can expand on that? do notation is only a shorthand. It is nothing else other than a shorthand. It exists because it's annoying to write (and read) something like a >>= \x -> m x p >>= \y -> n (y + q) when you could write do { x <- a; y <- m x p; n (y + q) }. The second thing is a shorthand for the first thing.

I am unsure about what you would consider "an uncommon implementation of bind". Take the Maybe monad, for instance. There, x >>= f does not call f when x=Nothing, short-cutting the computation. Similarly, do y <- Nothing ; ... does not care about the ... part. Is that "uncommon" for you?

On the one hand, there really is no way to understand <- "generically" once and for all, exactly because it is programmable. On the other hand, there do seem to be some patterns, so once you've understood it for ten monads, the eleventh gets much quicker to read. I think these days you could show me a new monad and I could pretty much just read the >>= implementation and grok it, and I expect that as you practice reading monad implementations you'll get there, too. (...except for Cont, that guy is like some sort of psychedelic; anything I understand wears off after a few hours.)

Beware the "contains a value" interpretation of m a. A monadic computation m a "contains" a value of type a in the same way that the Unix ls command "contains" a list of filenames.

@PaulJohnson In fact you can go further. Talking about "the value contained in an m a" is like talking about "the filename contained in a call to ls". ls can in some sense give you access to filenames, but you certainly can't talk about the filename unless you know a lot more specifics about the situation. Monad gives you a way of operating on the values if/when there are any (and a guarantee that =<< can handle the possibility of there being zero or multiple values without the operation needing to worry about it, unlike piping ls to another command).


I've noticed that bind (>>=) is often explained as applying the second argument (a function) to the value contained within the first argument and return the result of applying the function.  However, from the perspective of Monad laws, this doesn't seem to be the only possible implementation.

It must have something like this meaning, based on the types and the monad laws.  With foralls added in:
class Monad m where
  return :: forall a . a -> m a
  (>>=) :: forall a b . m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  ...

One law that Monads must follow is for any a and k, return a >>= k is equivalent to k a.  This makes it pretty clear that for all monads, a must be in some meaningful sense be "the value contained in" return a, and >>= must take that a out in some way and "return the result of applying" k to a.
Monads can naturally be much more complex.  For example, they don't have to contain exactly one a (see the list monad), nor do they have to have a value contained in them "yet" -- for example, an IO a is simply a recipe for producing an a when run.  But because of the law that return a >>= k is equivalent to k a, we are at least guaranteed that for all monads, there is a way to represent "this value alone," return, and when you do that, there must be a way to get it out and apply some follow-up function to it.
(>>=) does not overwrite anything -- you can't reassign the value associated with a variable.  To do anything like this, you end up needing something that boils down to recursion, where you're doing a new function call with a different value associated with a variable.  But by the monad laws, (>>=) must in fact always represent some progression of computation that can only move values from the left to the right.

Even without the actual laws, it's clear just from the type (>>=) :: forall a b . m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b that if >>= is to ever call the a -> m b function with a value of type a it can only have done so by obtaining such values from the m a structure. Since the a -> m b function corresponds to the remaining scope of the do block that has the bound variable in scope, you can tell that if that section of the block of ever run (which is not guaranteed, and could happen multiple times), the bound value "came from" the RHS of the binding arrow somehow.

I think State s might be a nicer example of not having a value yet than IO. It's relatively simple to re-implement and examine, containing no magic runtime integration.

Perhaps the simplest one is the list monad, which is implemented as:
instance Monad [] where
  return x = [x]
  x >>= f = [y | xi <- x, y <- f xi]
here x >>= f is essentially the same as concatMap f x that will thus for each element xi in the list x call f on that element, and the list of items f xi produces are added to the result.
this thus means that if we write:
foo :: [Int]
foo = do
    xi <- [1, 4, 2, 5]
    [xi, xi + 1]
it is translated as:
[1, 4, 2, 5] >>= \xi -> [xi, xi + 1]
and this will thus for each item in the list [1,4,2,5], yield x and x+1, so:
ghci> foo
[1,2,4,5,2,3,5,6]

Here the xi has type Int, not [Int].

then <- might no longer carry the semantics of C-style assignment or binding.

Well it does not really carry the semantics of a C-style assignment, not even with IO. In Haskell, you don't assign values to variables. You declare a variable, and that variable always keeps the same value. You thus can not make loops that for example would manipulate the value of a variable. Immutability is one of the core features of a declarative language.
